# Django rest swagger and json definition

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I'm pretty new to Django and I'm currently working on a project where Django-rest-framework is used and the documentation is created with Swagger trough the django-rest-swagger package.

I'm trying to find (or generate) a swagger.json definition file, any idea on where it can be found with this package? I would like to use it to generate client side code.

Thanks

Comment: are you referring to swagger setting where you can set title, description, contact etc.. for your api?

Comment: @Anush I'm referring to the API schema definition, like: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/examples/v2.0/json/petstore.json

Comment: for django-rest-swagger you need to add the SWAGGER_SETTINGS in your settings.py file. docs: http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html

Comment: Ok that is for configure the API docs, I found that I can generate that file with: https://github.com/signalfx/fetch-swagger-schema
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

The swagger schema definition can be generated with https://github.com/signalfx/fetch-swagger-schema regardless the api implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can append `?format=openapi` to the end of your docs URL and it will return the raw JSON text instead of the UI.

[see here](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/590#issuecomment-265569486)